# Use specific package name when setting up a react-native project

Tags: react-native

When creating a react-native app with `react-native init MyApp` the Android and iOS package names are automatically set to `com.myapp`.

Changing the Android package name (especially if you need something longer like `com.organisation.propject.app`) later in the development is pretty fiddly and I was wondering if there was a way to set the package name when setting up a project with `react-native init`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For React Native **>= 0.72**, use `--package-name` option.

```
$ react-native init MyApp --package-name=com.organization.project.app
```

---

For React Native versions between **0.40 - 0.72**, the parameter is not available as it was removed in ~0.40.

---

For React Native **< 0.40**, use `--package` option:

```
$ react-native init MyApp --package=com.organization.project.app
```

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to the source for this answer, please? I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: @amelzer, it's not documented and I have found it in the source code of `react-native-cli` - [here is the line for Android RN 37.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/890342ed881f27d19a77e518c2c59ea56c162668/local-cli/generator-android/index.js#L27). By the way, I am not able to find this option in master, so it is possible that the answer won't work with the latest react-native.

Comment: Yeah, it is not working anymore. Well, back to hacking, then :)

Comment: has someone created issue on GitHub related to this?

Comment: @ShukarullahShah Yes: [cant set package name #12721](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12721)

Comment: It is not working for me. If i use like this $react-native init MyApp --package=com.organization.myapp then it is creating package name like com.myapp

Comment: In RN 3.1.0, unknown option `--package'

Comment: This is not working with "react-native": "0.64.2"

Comment: use --package-name will work

Answer (score 7):

The below worked for me. Substitute your own app name for `"Foo App"` and your own package name for `org.newpackage.app`.

```
NEW_APP_NAME="Foo App"
NEW_PACKAGE_NAME=org.newpackage.app
OLD_PACKAGE_NAME=org.reactjs.native.example
npx react-native init rndemo && \
  cd rndemo && \
  npx react-native-rename "${NEW_APP_NAME}" -b ${NEW_PACKAGE_NAME} && \
  rm -rf ios/Pods && \
  pod install --project-directory=./iOS && \
  grep -rl ${OLD_PACKAGE_NAME} * | \
    xargs sed -i '.bak' "s/${OLD_PACKAGE_NAME}/${NEW_PACKAGE_NAME}/g"
```

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cunneen/6dc836565f9d831db134ca90bd6d1e22) that does this, prompting interactively for the app name and package name. The gist is a tiny bit more sophisticated, in that (in the above example) it would initially create the app `fooapp` instead of `rndemo`.

Explanation:

1. Create a react-native app. It's called `rndemo` temporarily; we need to know what it's going to be called so we can change to it.
2. Run react-native-rename to rename the new project to whatever you specified; this lets us replace the package name too.
3. Remove the installed cocoa pods and reinstall them (so they'll pick up the new folder locations etc).
4. Search for the default package name `org.reactjs.native.example` and replace it with your new package name. Currently this will only find `ios/FooApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. The old `project.pbxproj` file will be saved with a '.bak' extension. This step would probably be better done with `find . -name project.pbxproj -exec .....` but this was good enough for my needs.

Comment: cobberboy your gist was great, thanks for putting that together - I just successfully used it to init a project with a custom package name

Comment: @MikeHardy you're welcome, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

use this command:

```
npx react-native@latest init MyProject --package-name com.myproject.app
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options we can do with react native commands

```
Initialize a new React Native project named <projectName> in a directory of the same name.
    
    Options:
      --version <string>       Shortcut for `--template react-native@version`
      --template <string>      Uses a custom template. Valid arguments are the ones
                               supported by `yarn add [package]` or `npm install
                               [package]`, if you are using `--npm` option
      --npm                    Forces using npm for initialization
      --directory <string>     Uses a custom directory instead of `<projectName>`.
      --title <string>         Uses a custom app title name for application
      --skip-install           Skips dependencies installation step
      --package-name <string>  Inits a project with a custom package name (Android)
                               and bundle ID (iOS), e.g. com.example.app
      -h, --help               display help for command
```

*There is an option for the custom package name:*

```
react-native init MyApp --package-name com.organization.project.app
```