Facing "DEVELOPER_ERROR" in React Native app while trying to implement Google Login using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin
I'm trying to implement google login in my react native application using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin package. I followed all the steps in official documentation:(https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/original). Still facing the error.
I'm using Django as the backend and want to implement google login without using Firebase.
Below is my code for the google login implementation:
I was follwing this guide: https://peerlist.io/blog/engineering/implementing-google-signin-in-react-native
The expected outcome was to have my userInfo saved in my user state variable. But I'm entering the error catch block in GoogleLogin() with error statement:error fetching user info [Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR].
GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId:
      'xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    androidClientId:
      'xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosClientId:
      'xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
  });

  const GoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      return userInfo;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error fetching user info', error);
    }
  };

  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    setGLoginLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await GoogleLogin();
      const {idToken, user} = response;
      setUser(user);

      if (idToken) {
        const resp = await authAPI.validateToken({
          token: idToken,
          email: user.email,
        });
        await handlePostLoginData(resp.data);
      }
    } catch (apiError) {
      setGLoginError(
        apiError?.response?.data?.error?.message || 'Something went wrong',
      );
    } finally {
      setGLoginLoading(false);
    }
  };

Can Anyone help with this please?

Is that everything you get from the error?

Yes that is all, this is the whole statement: error fetching user info', [Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR]

I resolved the issue, but sadly can't post the answer here due to apparent answer ban.
I'll try in parts:
So I've figured out the solution to this issue.
Apparently, DEVELOPER_ERROR occur when the SHA-1 certificate and package name you provide while creating the client IDs for your app on google cloud console, are either wrong or the combination of both do not represent your application uniquely on GCP. Basically the combination of both should be unique and correct.

To get the package name of your react native application, either checkout your-app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml here package='xxx' will be your package name, or go to your-app\android\app\build.gradle here application Id will be your package name.

    android{
    ...
    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.xxx.yyyy"
         ...
      }
      ...
    }



In case you've been stuck like me and your package name is set to default when you first created your project using a template or default CLI command, you can set your package name while calling the CLI command for project initiation by setting a package-name flag
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init AwesomeProject --package-name=your.custom.packagename. [Reference][1], or you can also do it mannually [Reference1][2], [Reference2][3].

Also make sure you get your SHA-1 certificate from the signingReport.
Go to cd ./android then ./gradlew signingReport.
In the output, under the > Task :app:signingReport, choose the SHA-1 certificate with Variant: debugAndroidTest and Config: debug. This setup solved the issue for me and now google login was working perfectly.

Though I've come to this solution on my own by looking out at different answers and refrences online around my question. This is the solution that worked for me.
This can be used as a starting point to solve any similar issue. But DYOR!
Cheers✌️
References:
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282452/16788398
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390022/16788398
[3]: https://saumya.github.io/ray/articles/72/
[4]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816227/google-signin-sdk-is-failing-by-throwing-error-a-non-recoverable-sign-in-failur
